# Cumulative sum ignoring breaks

Tags: r, cumsum

Modified data:

```
structure(list(hour = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), cs = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L
), cs_acum = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L), cs_wanted = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L
), cs_acum2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 5L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 4L, 5L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("hour", "cs", "cs_acum", 
"cs_wanted", "cs_acum2"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -36L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000000001f0788>)
```

`cs_acum` is cumulative sum of `cs` with restart at 0.

```
df1$cs_acum <- with(df1, ave(df1$cs, cumsum(df1$cs == 0), FUN = cumsum))
```

I need this accumulation to continue if there is value of 1 in 5 rows of `hour` **after the accumulation of 1's from `cs` has stopped**.
Desired output is in col `cs_wanted`.

Further explanation: `çs_acum` is accumulation of hours (rows f `cs`) that meet certain criteria. After this, it has nothing to do with `cs` any more, it is then related to col: `hour`. The accumulation should continue if there is a value of 1 in 5 hour window after it has stopped.

Probably a new function checking five lines in `hour` from the position in `cs_acum` turns to 0, would be in order, continuing accumulation from where it has stopped in `cs_acum`.
Possible steps:
find position where accumulation stops
look at next five rows in hour
if there are values of 1, continue accumulation for that line,
look again in next five hours,
if there is no values of 1, do nothing.

---

New data:

```
df3 <- structure(list(hour = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
                      cs = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
                      cs_acum = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13), 
                      cs_acum2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0, 0, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28)), 
                 .Names = c("hour", "cs", "cs_acum", "cs_acum2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -68L))
```

Comment: I am not really sure how to explain it better. See the example accumulation in cs_wanted and it should be clear. if not I will give it another go.

Comment: Nope, I need sums of hours that are meeting certain criteria.

Answer (score 6):

Using:

```
library(data.table)

rl <- rle(df1$hour)

setDT(df1)[, grp := rleid(rep(rl$lengths >5 & rl$values == 0, rl$lengths))
           ][hour == 1, cs_acum2 := cumsum(hour), grp
             ][is.na(cs_acum2), cs_acum2 := 0][]
```

gives:

```
    hour cs cs_acum cs_wanted grp cs_acum2
 1:    1  1       1         1   1        1
 2:    1  1       2         2   1        2
 3:    1  1       3         3   1        3
 4:    0  0       0         0   1        0
 5:    0  0       0         0   1        0
 6:    1  0       0         4   1        4
 7:    1  0       0         5   1        5
 8:    0  0       0         0   2        0
 9:    0  0       0         0   2        0
10:    0  0       0         0   2        0
11:    0  0       0         0   2        0
12:    0  0       0         0   2        0
13:    0  0       0         0   2        0
14:    1  1       1         1   3        1
15:    1  1       2         2   3        2
16:    1  1       3         3   3        3
17:    0  0       0         0   3        0
```

Explanation:

- Convert the dataframe to a datatable with `setDT(df1)`.
- With `rl <- rle(d1$hour)` and `grp := rleid(rep(rl$lengths >5 & rl$values == 0, rl$lengths))` you create a grouping variable that only changes when there are more than 5 zero's.
- Next you filter by `hour == 1` and create a get the cumulative sum with `cumsum(hour)`. If your the values in `hour` are only `1`'s and `0`'s, you could also create a counter with `seq_along` or `1:.N` which will give the same result.
- Finally, with `is.na(cs_acum2), cs_acum2 := 0` you change the NA's to zero's.

---

**Update 1:** For the new example data (`df2`):

```
rl2 <- rle(df2$hour)

setDT(df2)[, `:=` (rn = .I, grp = rleid(rep(rl2$lengths >5 & rl2$values == 0, rl2$lengths)))
           ][hour == 1 & rn >= df2[, .I[cs == 1]][1], cs_acum2 := cumsum(hour), grp
             ][is.na(cs_acum2), cs_acum2 := 0][, c('rn','grp') := NULL][]
```

which gives:

```
    hour cs cs_acum cs_wanted cs_acum2
 1:    0  0       0         0        0
 2:    1  0       0         0        0
 3:    1  0       0         0        0
 4:    1  0       0         0        0
 5:    0  0       0         0        0
 6:    1  1       1         1        1
 7:    1  1       2         2        2
 8:    1  1       3         3        3
 9:    0  0       0         0        0
10:    0  0       0         0        0
11:    1  0       0         4        4
12:    1  0       0         5        5
13:    0  0       0         0        0
14:    0  0       0         0        0
15:    0  0       0         0        0
16:    0  0       0         0        0
17:    0  0       0         0        0
18:    0  0       0         0        0
19:    1  1       1         1        1
20:    1  1       2         2        2
21:    1  1       3         3        3
22:    0  0       0         0        0
```

The way I understood it is that the `cumsum` of `hour` is only allowed to start after the first appearance of `cs == 1`.

Additional explanation:

- With `rn = .I` you creat a rowindexnumber.
- `df2[, .I[cs == 1]][1]` give you the rownumber where `cs == 1` for the first time.
- With `rn >= df2[, .I[cs == 1]][1]` you select only the rows from that point onward.

---

**Update 2:** With regard to the latest (fourth) dataset, you could do:

```
rl4 <- rle(df4$hour)

setDT(df4)[, grp := rleid(rep(rl4$lengths >5 & rl4$values == 0, rl4$lengths))]

i1 <- df4[, .I[cs == 1][1], grp][!is.na(V1)]$V1
i2 <- df4[, .I[1:.N==5], rleid(cs)]$V1[-1] + 1

df4[i1, cs.inc := 1
    ][i2, cs.inc := -1
      ][is.na(cs.inc), cs.inc := 0
        ][, cs.inc := cumsum(cs.inc)
          ][hour == 1 & cs.inc == 1, cs_acum3 := cumsum(hour), grp
            ][is.na(cs_acum3), cs_acum3 := 0][, c('grp','cs.inc') := NULL][]
```

which gives:

```
    hour cs cs_acum cs_wanted cs_acum2 cs_acum3
 1:    0  0       0         0        0        0
 2:    1  0       0         0        0        0
 3:    1  0       0         0        0        0
 4:    1  0       0         0        0        0
 5:    0  0       0         0        0        0
 6:    1  1       1         1        1        1
 7:    1  1       2         2        2        2
 8:    1  1       3         3        3        3
 9:    0  0       0         0        0        0
10:    0  0       0         0        0        0
11:    1  0       0         4        4        4
12:    1  0       0         5        5        5
13:    0  0       0         0        0        0
14:    0  0       0         0        0        0
15:    0  0       0         0        0        0
16:    0  0       0         0        0        0
17:    0  0       0         0        0        0
18:    0  0       0         0        0        0
19:    1  1       1         1        1        1
20:    1  1       2         2        2        2
21:    1  1       3         3        3        3
22:    0  0       0         0        0        0
23:    0  0       0         0        0        0
24:    0  0       0         0        0        0
25:    0  0       0         0        0        0
26:    0  0       0         0        0        0
27:    0  0       0         0        0        0
28:    0  0       0         0        0        0
29:    1  0       0         0        1        0
30:    1  0       0         0        2        0
31:    1  0       0         0        3        0
32:    0  0       0         0        0        0
33:    1  1       1         1        4        1
34:    1  1       2         2        5        2
35:    0  0       0         0        0        0
36:    0  0       0         0        0        0
```

---

**Used data**

First example dataset:

```
df1 <- structure(list(hour = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), 
                      cs = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), 
                      cs_acum = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L), 
                      cs_wanted = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L)),
                 .Names = c("hour", "cs", "cs_acum", "cs_wanted"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -17L))
```

Second dataset:

```
df2 <- structure(list(hour = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L),
                      cs = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L),
                      cs_acum = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L),
                      cs_wanted = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L)),
                 .Names = c("hour", "cs", "cs_acum", "cs_wanted"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -22L))
```

Fourth dataset:

```
df4 <- structure(list(hour = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), 
                      cs = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), 
                      cs_acum = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L), 
                      cs_wanted = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L), 
                      cs_acum2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 4L, 5L, 0L, 0L)), 
                 .Names = c("hour", "cs", "cs_acum", "cs_wanted", "cs_acum2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -36L))
```

Comment: same problem happens on this data set, but look at row 48.

Comment: see modified data set, accumulation in row 29, after running your code

Comment: I am afraid that again, we have the same problem. It is not usable for other data sets. thanks a lot for the effort.

Comment: @m_c As far as I can judge now based on the different datasets, I afraid the approach has to be tailored to the dataset.

Comment: yes, but since I have few hundreds of them..... Do you think a function would be appropriate? or a loop, to activate only in cast there is accumulation? I tried to figure it out but did not work for me...

Comment: @m_c I'm willing to look into that, but then you will have to describe precisely all the conditions that apply. Up to now, I needed to guess based on the different dataset you posted. So, please include a detailed description of what you want to achieve in the question.

Comment: I have tried to explain to the best of my ability. main point is that accumulation in cs_acum continues whenever there is 1 in following 5 hours.

Answer (score 1):

We can try this using **only** data.table methods

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[,  grp := shift(cumsum(hour == 1 & (Reduce(`+`, 
   shift(hour, 1:5, fill = 1, type = "lead"))==0)), fill=0)
     ][hour ==1, cs_acum1 := cumsum(hour) , grp
      ][is.na(cs_acum1), cs_acum1 := 0][, grp := NULL][]
#     hour cs cs_acum cs_wanted cs_acum1
# 1:    1  1       1         1        1
# 2:    1  1       2         2        2
# 3:    1  1       3         3        3
# 4:    0  0       0         0        0
# 5:    0  0       0         0        0
# 6:    1  0       0         4        4
# 7:    1  0       0         5        5
# 8:    0  0       0         0        0
# 9:    0  0       0         0        0
#10:    0  0       0         0        0
#11:    0  0       0         0        0
#12:    0  0       0         0        0
#13:    0  0       0         0        0
#14:    1  1       1         1        1
#15:    1  1       2         2        2
#16:    1  1       3         3        3
#17:    0  0       0         0        0
```

**Explanation**

We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), create a grouping variable using the `lead` values of 'hour' to create the condition in the OP's post, specify the 'i' (`hour==1`) grouped by 'grp' and assign (`:=`) the `cumsum` of 'hour' as 'cs_acum1', change the NA elements ito 0 and lastly remove the 'grp' by assigning it to `NULL`

Comment: I dont understand how is this duplicate question of the one you have linked to?

Comment: I managed to run it on wider set, found it is not giving me what I want. I need the accumulation to continue only if it has started already in `cs_acum`

Comment: @m_c Thanks for the update.  I see the other poster working hard on each of your updates.  So, I don't want to spoil his efforts :-)

Comment: if you think you can figure it out dont be shy! :)